# Cakephp 2.2 display multiple views in the home page

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am new to cake. I have baked an application with CRUD and now I wanted  setup Authentication. I wanted to show two forms for eg login.ctp and add.ctp ( which is a user registration form) in my home page. But to display add.ctp,I have used routing like

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

Is this the right way to do it? How to show specific views/forms in the default layout?

Answer (score 2):

Elements are great for re-using "views" on different pages!

Move your code from login.ctp and add.ctp to the Elements directory, e.g.

`Elements/userLogin.ctp` & `Elements/userAdd.ctp`

and refer to those elements in e.g. `User/login.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $this->element('userLogin'); ?>
```

now create a `HomeController`, and give it an `index` action, and `Home/index.ctp`.

in `Home/index.ctp`:

```
<?php echo $this->element('userLogin'); ?>

<?php echo $this->element('userAdd'); ?>
```

and route to it:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

How's that?

Comment: Just to be clear, I wouldn't refer to elements as `views` as the term view has its own separate meaning.  Though, this is exactly how to achieve @ThurleyT 's requirements.